# Structure RESTful Tornado Web App

Tags: python, design-patterns, tornado

[Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/) uses classes which derive from `tornado.web.RequestHandler` to define `post` and `get` methods. I have created a request handler for the path `r/action/*`

Since there are different more concrete paths, like `action/doThis` and `action/requestThat` I have structured the `get` method with a if-then-else structure checking for the concrete request URI.

**That seems very clumsy, is there a more sophisticated way to structure that, for instance with methods?** Or would the Tornado way be to just define more RequestHandlers? I like the way [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) does it with Function Decorators, but since they are Python 3, this is not an option at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Decorators are not limited to Python 3; I use `bottle` with 2.7 frequently (I prefer the decorator syntax and the lighter weight of `bottle` when prototyping interfaces, or when I don't find my implementation needing the class-based behavior of `Tornado`).

That said, if `action/doThis` and `action/requestThat` provide different behavior, would you be better served by defining them as separate routes? If they share some aspects of their behavior, you could always have both `RequestHandler` subclasses share a common base.

```
class HandleAction(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def take_appropriate_action(route):
        print("Responding to action/{}".format(route))


class HandleThis(HandleAction):
    def get(self):
        self.take_appropriate_action('doThis')


class HandleThat(HandleAction):
    def get(self):
        self.take_appropriate_action('requestThat')


app = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/action/doThis', HandleThis),
    (r'/action/requestThat', HandleThat)
])
```

Answer (score 1):

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176185/tornado-restful-handler-classes) and the first answer I would agree with. Because of the lack of features that Tornado provides you have to roll your own solutions or use somnething like [Tornado Addons](https://github.com/nod/tornado_addons) which would ease the annoyance of creating the necessary handlers and their associated routes.

```
from tornado_addons.route import route

@route( "/action/doThis" )
class HandleDoThis( Request ):
 pass

@route( "/action/requestThat" )
class HandleRequestThat:
 pass

app = tornado.web.Application( route.get_routes() )
```

This would make it much more viable to create separate handler classes for each of your RESTful resources. This would clean up your `if` statement worries.