# Tornado how handler restful routes

Tags: python, rest, tornado, restful-url

I'm try to do a RESTFul Api with tornado framework but i don't have idea how handler the url routes for the handlers, I try to do something like this [Tornado Restful Handler Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176185/tornado-restful-handler-classes) this cuestion is 3 years ago and i ask if now exists a better way for do that.
Now exist a elegant way for handler the url routes of RESTFul API?

Comment: its already so elegant. Tornado already is doing a lot of work, what else do we need.

Answer (score 3):

```
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.write("Hello, world")

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.write("Hello, world")

class IDHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        _id = args[0]
        self.write(_id)

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
    (r"/(\d+)$", IDHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

if your request `http://127.0.0.1:8888/` in `get` or `post` method your give 'Hello, world'

if you request  `http://127.0.0.1:8888/12` in `post` method your give '12'